# Why container-fluid is leaving blank space on right side

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

When I use the container-fluid, it is leaving some space on the right side of my web page. I am fairly new to bootstrap so if anyone can help me, it would be much appreciated.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid" style="border: solid 1px blue">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: As you can see there is some space after the blue border]

Comment: Can you show us some more code if possible so we can recreate the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Have you linked Bootstrap to your theme / file?
- Are you sure you don't have global styling that causes that right space?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the global styling it was causing the problem I am very new to CSS so that's why making silly mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You did not give enough details. Anyway looks like your entire document goes a little bit left because I can't see the left border. If you can send the full code I can be more specific

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had an external CSS file which was causing the problem

Comment: Not an answer, next time add it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't linked Bootstrap to your file. Please check it and try again. In my case, It's working perfectly.

[image]

Comment: Ahh, I had an external CSS file linked to the HTML that's why this was happening. Sorry for the trouble guys and thank you for the reply

Answer (score 0):

As there is nothing in your div so "1" comes at the start of first div and "2" at the start of second div. That's why you think there is space on right of second div , but actually content is starting from the beginning of each child-div.